# Multi-variate maximization over a table

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, max, minimum

I'm looking for a simple to implement algorithm that can find the row of a table having the maximum value on a certain column. Then, it should find all the rows that have a value close to the maximum on that particular column (can these 2 steps be combined?). Then, out of the selected rows, I need to find the one that has the minimum value on another column.

Bonus: in case there are several such entries, I need to find the row having the minimum value on another column.

Yes, I am aware that it's easy to do this with SQL(ite), but I don't want to waste time parsing the data from my text file into a database table...

I am interested in a simple idea on how to do this (pseudocode is fine) and, right now, I can only think of something rather complex along these lines:

- iterate over all rows & find maximum
- iterate over all rows and insert the ones that are "close" to the maximum in a list
- find minimum value in the new list of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are doing the right thing. Unless your row values are **already sorted**, you can't avoid going through all values in step 1, so you will end up spending `O(R)` time in there, where `R` is the number of rows.

For the second step, its cost is also `O(R)` so it doesn't degrade your algorithm's complexity.

If we consider that the number of values "close to the maximum" is `O(1)` with respect to `R`, then the third step is `O(C)` where `C` is the number of columns. You can't do better than this **if your values aren't sorted** because you need to test all values in order to find the minimum.

Your algorithm has the **best complexity you will get**.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. I'm not that worried about complexity, since there are at most 30k rows or so, but I have to redesign the stupid script that I'm currently using :(

Answer (score 0):

My take on this:

- Sort your table on that first column, row-wise
- The maximum value is the first or last value in this sorted column
- All values close by are a as close by as possible to the maximum in the sorted column
- Extract those rows
- Sort again on the second column
- Find the minimum just like above...
- If there are several such entries, sort again with the third column...

The speed of this is defined by the sorting algorithm used.

Comment: OK, I just realized that you don't want to parse your data at all.
In case you still want to this with arrays or other similar data structures, give a try :)

Comment: It seems that I can't avoid parsing it and going over it one more time in-memory, so, yeah, parsing it and inserting it in an ordered list seems to be a decent approach. Thanks!

Comment: The speed of this is `O(nlogn)` and it's only worth the pain if you make the same query over the **same column** at least `log(n)` times. This is actually a bad idea.

Comment: @alestanis I hate it when I have to do such things in a rush. Thanks for pointing out the complexity.